# Getting all objects in array within date range?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this sample array:

```
[{"people":100,"started":"2020-08-04T19:23:32.823Z"},{"people":55,"started":"2020-08-05T16:12:32.823Z"},{"people":200,"started":"2020-08-06T11:22:32.823Z"}]
```

How can I make a function that will give me the objects where the `started` date is between two date ranges?

For example, between the date `2020-08-05` and `2020-08-06` would return object 2 and 3 from the example array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const array = [{"people":100,"started":"2020-08-04T19:23:32.823Z"},{"people":55,"started":"2020-08-05T16:12:32.823Z"},{"people":200,"started":"2020-08-06T11:22:32.823Z"}]

console.log(array.filter(group=>{
    return new Date(group.started) > new Date("2020-08-05") && new Date(group.started) < new Date("2020-08-06")
}))
```